# Extract the UML code from an IntelliJ diagram

Tags: intellij-idea, uml, class-diagram, intellij-14, plantuml

After creating a class diagram in the usual way (Right click in the project view -> Diagrams -> Show diagram), I can save it as a `.uml` file. This works fine.

My question is: is there any way of extracting the UML code that shapes this diagram? Is there a corresponding UML code at all, or IntelliJ builds the diagram in some other way?

With *UML diagram* I mean something like this (taken from http://plantuml.com/class-diagram):

```
@startuml
Class01 <|-- Class02
Class03 *-- Class04
Class05 o-- Class06
Class07 .. Class08
Class09 -- Class10
@enduml
```

**TL;DR:** Having the diagram is nice, but what I would like to have is the UML code that shapes the diagram.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by 'uml code'? UML is a graphical language, it's not codified apart from, arguably, XMI, as far as I am aware. Is this an InteliJ specific thing?

Comment: You are completely right. I was asking for the 'plantUML' code. Which, of course, I will not be able to generate. I though that the type of code I saw in the link was generic, but it seems it is just plantUML. Thank you. I guess this question can be closed